# Jetty 8 initContext.lookup("java:comp/env") javax.naming.NameNotFoundException

Tags: java, dependency-injection, jetty, jndi

The below code:

```
Context initContext = new InitialContext();
bm = (BeanManager) ((Context)initContext.lookup("java:comp/env")).lookup("BeanManager");
```

Fails with the following error:

> javax.naming.NameNotFoundException; remaining name 'env' at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.jndi.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:449) at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.jndi.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:536) at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.jndi.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:551)

I am using jetty 8. The idea is to load BeanManager, but it looks like it is not even getting to that part. Why would 'env' cannot be found? I thought it was something that is supposed to be there as part of the jvm.

Content of /WEB-INF/web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>log4j-config-location</param-name>
        <param-value>WEB-INF/classes/log4j.properties</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>HelloServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
      <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <resource-env-ref>
        <resource-env-ref-name>BeanManager</resource-env-ref-name>
        <resource-env-ref-type>
            javax.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager
        </resource-env-ref-type>
    </resource-env-ref>
</web-app>
```

Content of jetty-web.xml

```
<Configure id="webAppCtx" class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
    <New id="BeanManager" class="org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jndi.Resource">
        <Arg>
            <Ref id="webAppCtx"/>
        </Arg>
        <Arg>env/BeanManager</Arg>
        <Arg>
            <New class="javax.naming.Reference">
                <Arg>javax.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager</Arg>
                <Arg>org.jboss.weld.resources.ManagerObjectFactory</Arg>
                <Arg/>
            </New>
        </Arg>
    </New>
</Configure>
```

content of jetty-plus.xml

```
<Configure id="Server" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server">
<!-- =========================================================== -->
<!-- Add plus Configuring classes to all webapps for this Server -->
<!-- =========================================================== -->
  <Call class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.Configuration$ClassList" name="setServerDefault">
    <Arg><Ref refid="Server" /></Arg>
    <Call name="addAfter">
      <Arg name="afterClass">org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.FragmentConfiguration</Arg>
      <Arg>
        <Array type="String">
        <Item>org.eclipse.jetty.plus.webapp.EnvConfiguration</Item>
        <Item>org.eclipse.jetty.plus.webapp.PlusConfiguration</Item>
      </Array>
    </Arg>
  </Call>
</Call>
</Configure>
```

I'm new to jetty. Also, in the .xml files, I don't have a reference to the name of my webapp. Not sure if I read all the examples wrong or this is because the .xml files reside inside the corresponding webapp/WEB-INF dir. The 'id' in the xml is just random string?

Comment: [Jetty 8 is EOL (End of Life)](https://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/jetty-announce/msg00069.html), consider upgrading to something supported and stable, such as Jetty 9.2+.

Comment: Replace `<Arg>env/BeanManager</Arg>` with `<Arg>BeanManager</Arg>` and add the listener in your web.xml 
`<listener>

   <listener-class>org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.BeanManagerResourceBindingListener</listener-class>`

Comment: as described [here](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html/environments.html#_jetty)

Comment: After adding the `<listener>`, jetty won't even start :(